# Getting Video call pop up after decline video call?

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox

I am using QuickBlox video call API.

Sometime I am getting unnecessary video call pop up after declining video call.

Steps :

1. Call User2 from User1 and decline it from User2 device.
   Result: Declined pop up appear that is ok.
2. Now call User1 from User2 and decline.
   Result : unnecessary video call pop up appearing on again if user decline call

Anyone know how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it on the app side,

for example if a user declined call and received another incoming request from the same user during next 2 seconds for example - just ignore it

Comment: Hi Igor Khomenko I will really appreciate you if you will fix this issue in your video chat sample provided by you by which so many another developer will not get this issue in future.

Comment: hey vijeesh you can take code reference from http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-videochat-ios .

Comment: I have this sample, I just completed my video chat app n its working fine

Comment: @vijeesh Did you test your code with above steps?? Are you getting any pop up like ""Would you like to answer" again and again if you decline the call??

Comment: Let me check, i'll get back to you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70770/discussion-between-007-and-vijeesh).